# Result empty when date variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle 10g Database. I have a table with a lot of information. One of the columns has a type of DATE declared as follows `DATE_INSERT DATE`. I'm trying to make a query and have it filtered by a specific Date. When I use the function `TO_CHAR()` in the where clause I get the information as expected

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE_INSERT, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = '05/10/2018'
```

But when I use a DATE variable or the `TO_DATE()` function I get an empty result set.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_INSERT = TO_DATE('05/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_INSERT = date '2018-10-05';
```

OR (`date_var` defined as a date previously)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE_INSERT = date_var;
```

By a DB department requirement I need to get rid of all functions TO_DATE() / TO_CHAR(). Can you help me know why is the filtering not working when DATE types are used in the query?

Comment: Use `date '2018-05-10'`. It needs ISO format.

Comment: I have already used that as well. I can edit the post but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the time component.  I would recommend either:

```
WHERE DATE_INSERT >= date '2018-10-05' AND
      DATE_INSERT < date '2018-10-06'
```

Or:

```
WHERE TRUNC(DATE_INSERT) = date '2018-10-05'
```

Oracle supports function-based indexes.  If you want an index to be used, you can create an index to support either of these queries.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` column **always** stores the date and the time information. So the query you mention:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE_INSERT, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = '05/10/2018'

doesn't use equality, but queries for a range. Which range? The whole day, that is 24 hours.

For the other query to you'll need to use a range, as in:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
  WHERE DATE_INSERT >= TO_DATE('05/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND DATE_INSERT < TO_DATE('06/10/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

More clearly, to show the date & time info:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
  WHERE DATE_INSERT >= TO_DATE('05/10/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    AND DATE_INSERT < TO_DATE('06/10/2018 00:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```